# Include Bootstrap to Typo3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I worked with Typo3 4.5 and already have included the YAML CSS Framework with TemplaVoila.
But now I have installed Typo3 6.1 and want to include the Bootstrap Framework.
But I don´t know if it is better to use TemplaVoila or to use the normal Template.

And I am not quite sure how to include the Bootstrap framework.
My first idea is to copy the framework files to fileadmin folder.
Then include the css and js files that are in the docs/index.html (example file) to my TS Template and than I can create the HTML content.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Take a look at modern package: https://github.com/georgringer/modernpackage and the bootstrap demo: http://bootstrap.typo3cms.demo.typo3.org/

Answer (score 1):

Frontend template extensions that take over a large part of the template rendering can sometimes be confusing. If you understand the rendered page template as the end product that's generated by the CMS, but not a part of the CMS's functionality, everything will become easier and more transparent (less black boxes).

My advice would be: don't use a framework extension, get bootstrap from github, ideally in the LESS version - use one of the many lessphp extensions to parse less while developing - and create your template in whichever templating system you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter if you are using TV or 'standard' templating system, just include the Bootstrap in your headers and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Find an example at the official TYPO3 homepage: http://bootstrap.typo3cms.demo.typo3.org/